# Android: Read String from file

Tags: android, input

I am having some trouble reading a String from a ".txt" file on my external storage.
The method i created is not working for my program and i need some help with it

```
private String readFromFile() {

String ret = "";

try {

final File configDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "config");

    configDir.mkdir();

    InputStream inputStream = openFileInput(new File(configDir, "url.txt"));

    if ( inputStream != null ) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        ret = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
}

return ret;
}
```

I really do not know how to solve this and get this method to work for my program.
It would be great if someone of you could help me.

Comment: Are you receiving any exceptions? If so please include your stack trace/log in your question, so we can better help you.

Comment: And add e.printStackTrace() to both exceptions so we can see the cause.

Comment: Thank you both but @Hamid Shatu got the solution for my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileReader` instead of `InputStreamReader` and correct `configDir` creation as below...

```
try {

    final File configDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/config");

    configDir.mkdir();

    File file = new File(configDir, "url.txt");

    if ( inputStream != null ) {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String receiveString = "";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
            stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        ret = stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but i had to close the bufferedReader too. But the rest worked fine for me!